# Two different answers when calculating MSEP

Tags: r, regression

I would appreciate help with understanding why I get two different answers when I calculate MSEP (mean square error prediction) in two different ways using R, both for simple linear regression and multilinear regression.

**Background**: I am working on a task where I have to carry out both simple linear and multilinear regression. In this task I have three explanatory variables, tar, nico and weight and have predicted CO for the multilinear regression. For the simple linear regressions I created one for each of the explanatory variable where I predicted CO. Hence, Co is the dependent variable in both cases. Now I want to check which model should be used for prediction using mean square error prediction (MSEP).

**Now**: I found two ways to calculate MSEP in R, one was through `ols_msep(model)` where I had to download the library olsrr. And the second where through the following code, which was given in my course literature for this purpose (i.e. calculation MSEP):

```
glmfit=glm(model)
mean(glmfit$residuals^2/(1-glm.diag(glmfit)$h)^2)
```

and for this I needed to download the library boot.

**However**: When I use both of these to calculate MSEP for the same model, I get different answers. How does this happen? When I run the first code `ols_msep(model)` I get the value `52.4955` but when I run the second code I get the value `3.579102`. Is there anyone who might have used these codes before and knows why this occurs?

Any tips are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run `mean((y - predictions)^2)`, suitable adapted to your variable names. If any of your functions disagree with this result (aside from tiny rounding differences), they’re wrong. (Why is this code the correct answer?)

Comment: Thank you @Dave for tour answer, but isn't that for the MSE and not the MSEP?

Comment: What’s the difference?

Comment: In my literature book it said that MSEP=MSE*N/(N-1). But maybe I've misunderstood that this means they would be different.

Comment: Then you have your equation. Which of the functions you use matches that one?

Comment: None of them actually, but I found another function in R which gave me the same answer as your code `mean((y - predictions)^2)` so this one seems to be the most reliable.